# Will parallel spring balances vs single spring balance with same mass give the same reading?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

So, if we have two identical spring balances and attach a 1kg mass, and then take another 1 kg mass and attach it to one spring balance, will we get the same reading? I tried to draw free body diagrams for the situations, and if we look at each spring as a separate system, it looks like the same forces apply on them, and the reading would be the same. Is that correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No if you attach a weight on two springs (parallel) every one of them takes half the weight. It is the same if yo carry a heavy weight alone or have a second person help.

Comment: But then when we attach two spring balances in series, why do they show the same reading?

Comment: If you attach them in series the weight is suspended on one point, the upper spring shows the weight of the lower pring + the weight of the mass. To keep the example of two persons, It does not help the lower person if you lift her up, she has still to carry the full weight!

Comment: Thank for the analogy! :)